# Finding Palindromes from the product of two numbers with N digits

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

My code compiles but seems as if it may never find the answer. This is odd since I have looked at code that is almost identical that finishes in seconds.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <sstream>

int main()
{
       for(int i = 999; i >=100; i--)
       {
              for(int j=999; j>=100;j--)
              {
                     int num = (i*j);
                     std::string number;
                     std::string temp;
                     std::string reversed;
                     std::stringstream out;
                     out << num;
                     number = out.str();
                     temp = number;
                     std::reverse(temp.begin(),temp.end());
                     if( temp == number)
                     {
                           std::cout << number << std::endl;
                     }

              }
       }



       std::cin.get();
       return 0;
}
```

Now here is code that I know works and works incredibly fast. I don't see what we are doing differently.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Count down from largest to smallest, so first palindrome found is the largest

    unsigned biggestProduct = 0;

    for(unsigned n1=999; n1>=100; --n1) {
        for(unsigned n2=999; n2>=100; --n2) {
            unsigned thisProduct = n1 * n2;

            if(thisProduct > biggestProduct) {
                stringstream strmProduct;
                string strProductReverse;

                strmProduct << n1 * n2;

                strProductReverse = strmProduct.str();
                reverse(strProductReverse.begin(), strProductReverse.end());

                if(strmProduct.str() == strProductReverse)
                    biggestProduct = thisProduct;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << biggestProduct << endl;
    cin.get();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000168/project-euler-problem-4

Comment: Yes but I want to know what is wrong with my code specifically.

Comment: I think the lesson here is don't stare at code. Learn how to use a *debugger*, you would have found the problem in seconds.

Comment: @tedled: You already been given the answer, see Ziyao Wei's answer.

Comment: That was a copy/paste error from my code. It was an error in the post.

Comment: @tedled: OK, care to edit your post so the code is correct? Will avoid confusion and help you get an answer.

Comment: I tried your code, it runs for less than 2 second, which is fine (a bit slow, but fine). What you said was that the code "may never find the answer". Perhaps there are some differences between your actual code and the one you used before posting?

Answer (score 4):

```
for(int i = 999; i <=100; i--)
```

Will this ever run (same for j)? :)

```
for(int i = 999; i >=100; i--)
```

Comment: I changed it from starting at 100 to 900 and didn't change it in my post. It is correct in my code.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest difference is this line `if(thisProduct > biggestProduct)`. If the product is smaller than the current biggest you don't have to check whether is palindrome.

Answer (score 1):

OK, assuming a correction to the for loops, there's an important difference in the two pieces of code. The second faster piece of code only attempts to find the largest palindrome, so it avoids a lot of work. Your code attempts to find all palindromes which is obviously a harder problem and is going to take more time.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is that the first tests for palindromeness for every `i*j`, while the other only tests `i*j` greater than the biggest palindrome its already found.

It can be made slightly faster by going from `j= i` to `j>=100` and earlying out when `i*j<= biggestProduct` or when `i*i<= biggestProduct`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple issues I can point to:

- This line of code: `for(int j=999; j>=100;j--)` can be reduced to `for(int j=999; j>=i-1;j--)`.This is to avoid running through number twice. 
  example: for `i=999` you will go through `j` counter, starting with 999, followed by 998, 997, etc. It would save time if you skip everything lower or equal to 998 since `i=<998` and `j=999` would make those combinations
- The second hint is in the question: you are looking for the largest, meaning that the first palindrome is the largest. So you need to filter whatever combination you have beyond that. You have it in the second code by adding `if(thisProduct > biggestProduct)`.
- Also steps for the counter can be crucial. From [this discussion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145396/generalized-project-euler-4-largest-palindrome-from-product-of-two-n-digit-num?answertab=oldest#tab-top) I found that changing the step size to 2 could be useful.
- Last but not least is strings. I learnt [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145396/generalized-project-euler-4-largest-palindrome-from-product-of-two-n-digit-num?answertab=oldest#tab-top) also that making strings could be computationally expensive. Editing the block with `std::string` could be another option.