# Optimizing the largest palindrome from product of two three digit numbers?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, palindrome

I am working on an interview question which I was asked in which I was supposed to write a program to find the largest palindrome from product of two three digit numbers.

Here is the [question](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4)

I came up with this brute force approach which starts from bottom.

```
public class LargestPalindromeQuestion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int value = 0;
        for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j <= 999; j++) {
                int value1 = i * j;
                if (isPalindrome(value1) && value < value1) {
                    value = value1;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    private static boolean isPalindrome(final int product) {
        int p = product;
        int reverse = 0;
        while (p != 0) {
            reverse *= 10;
            reverse += p % 10;
            p /= 10;
        }
        return reverse == product;
    }
}
```

They asked me what are the optimizations I can do in this program? I mentioned that we can try pruning the search space and optimize checking step for each item in the search space but then I am confuse how would I make this work in my above solution?

What are the optimizations we can do in this program? Right now it is executing `810000` steps to find the largest palindrome.

What is the least number of steps we can execute to find the largest palindrome in two three digit numbers?

Comment: this might help (i'm just working on the same problem, so i haven't read it yet) http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-problem-4/

Comment: Assuming that leading zeros are not allowed to be part of the palindrome, any numbers ending in zero cannot be palindromes. So you can skip all values of i and j where i % 10 == 0 or j % 10 == 0, because multiplying by a value ending in 0 gives a result ending in 0.

Answer (score 4):

The program looks very good to me. I would make the `i` loop count from `999` down to `100`, and I would only check `j` values that would actually give a larger product than the current maximum.

This program is able to finish surprisingly soon, at `i == 952` to be precise. The mathematical reason for this is that once the solution `906609` (`993 * 913`) is found, it will no longer be possible to find a larger palindrome where the larger factor is less than the square-root of `906609`, which is `952.160...`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
        int r = value / i;
        if (r >= i) {
            System.out.println("We broke at i = " + i);
            break;
        }
        for (int j = i; j > r; j--) {
            int value1 = i * j;
            if (isPalindrome(value1)) {
                value = value1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me this line `"The mathematical reason for this is that once the solution 906609 (993 * 913) is found, it will no longer be possible to find a larger palindrome"`? I am not able to understand why we won't be able to find larger palindrome after that?

Comment: @david In this code, `i` means the larger of the two 3 digit numbers. If `i <= 952` then `j` will also be `<= 952` (because it is less than or equal to `i`), so `i * j` will be less than `906609`, which means there's no point carrying on.

Answer (score 1):

One pretty simple way of optimizing this would be to simply start with the highest 3-digit numbers instead of the smallest. Since the solution will most likely be closer to the pair (999 , 999) than to (100 , 100).

Comment: This is good. If you use a `break;` statement when you do find the first palindrome, this will cut down the number of steps. You won't be able to get a good estimate, but it will cut down on the unnecessary steps for checking low numbers like < 500.

Comment: If you count down i from 999 to 100, you can break after you have found a palindrome and i * 999 is less than the highest palindrome you have found, because after that it's impossible to find a higher one. You can also break in the inner loop (but not the outer) if j is counting down once i * j is less than the highest found so far

Comment: There is no proof for this statement , it also be possible that maximum palindrome occurs at <500 so then this method will take longer time. This answer has been reverse engineered might fail for generalized case of n*n palindrome.

Comment: @Vikram Bhat i've tried it. and it's **far** closer to (999 , 999) than (100 , 100). Apart from that there are a lot of pairs (n , n) that generate palindromes. You're right it's only a guess, but by taking a look at the numbers you might notice that it's reasonable.

Comment: @VikramBhat if you count upwards then you cant ever break because you never know if you are going to find a higher one. So this way is faster even if it is < 500

Comment: @samgak agree with that statement but not the reason mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 1):

One useful mechanism to prune the search tree is to notice that the highest digit of the product `a * b` doesn't change often. E.g.

```
a = 111;   b = 112   a*b = 12432
       ;   b = 113   a*b = 12543
       ;   b = 114   a*b = 12654
       ;   ...
       ;   b = 180   a*b = 19980
       ;   b = 181   a*b = 20091 = (19980 + a)
```

Thus, for all the values in between (a = 111, a < b < 181), one already knows the MSB, which must equal to the LSB or (a % 10) * (b % 10) % 10 == MSB.

```
 e.g.
 LSB = 1    --> a % 10 == 1, b % 10 == 1
            OR  a % 10 == 3, b % 10 == 7
            OR  a % 10 == 7, b % 10 == 3
            OR  a % 10 == 9, b % 10 == 9
```

Most of the time there's either none, or just one candidate in set 'b' to be checked for any pair MSB, a % 10.

Answer (score 0):

The least number of steps I could get to is 375. Consider multiplying the three-digit number, `a1a2a3`, by the three-digit number, `b1b2b3`:

JavaScript code:

```
var modHash = new Array(10);
var iterations = 0;

for (var i=1; i<10; i++){
  modHash[i] = {0: [0]}
  for (var j=1; j<10; j++){
    iterations ++;
    var r = i * j % 10;
    if (modHash[i][r])
      modHash[i][r].push(j);
    else 
      modHash[i][r] = [j];
  }
}

var highest = 0;

function multiples(x,y,carry,mod){

  for (var i in modHash[x]){
    var m = (10 + mod - i - carry) % 10;

    if (modHash[y][m]){
      for (var j in modHash[x][i]){
        for (var k in modHash[y][m]){
          iterations ++;
          var palindrome = num(9,modHash[y][m][k],x,9,modHash[x][i][k],y);

          if (x == 3 && mod == 0){
            console.log(x + " * " + modHash[x][i][j] + " + " 
                        + y + " * " + modHash[y][m][k] + ": " + palindrome);
          }

          var str = String(palindrome);

          if (str == str.split("").reverse().join("") && palindrome > highest){
            highest = palindrome;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function num(a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3){
  return (100*a1 + 10*a2 + a3)
       * (100*b1 + 10*b2 + b3);
}

var a3b3s = [[7,7,4],[9,1,0],[3,3,0]];

for (var i in a3b3s){
  for (var mod=0; mod<10; mod++){
    var x = a3b3s[i][0],
        y = a3b3s[i][1],
        carry = a3b3s[i][2];
    multiples(x,y,carry,mod);
  }
}

console.log(highest);
console.log("iterations: " + iterations);
```

Output:

```
3 * 0 + 3 * 0: 815409 
3 * 7 + 3 * 3: 907809 
3 * 4 + 3 * 6: 908109 
3 * 1 + 3 * 9: 906609 
3 * 8 + 3 * 2: 907309 
3 * 5 + 3 * 5: 908209 
3 * 2 + 3 * 8: 907309 
3 * 9 + 3 * 1: 906609 
3 * 6 + 3 * 4: 908109 
3 * 3 + 3 * 7: 907809
906609
iterations: 375
```

Answer (score 0):

First optimize isPalindrome by seperating 6 digits as 3 digits. i.e. N = ABCDEF => a = ABC = N/1000, b = DEF = N%1000; Then reverse b and return a==reversed_b;

Secondly while producing palindromes loop through till max_palindrome_so_far/999 which is the minimum value that you would use. max_palindrome_so_far is initially equals N.

```
public class Solution {

    public static boolean isPalindrome(int n){
        int a = n/1000;
        int b = n%1000;
        int d, r = 0, i = 3;
        while(i-- > 0){
            d = b%10;
            r = r*10 + d;
            b = b/10;
        }
        if (a == r)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
            int n = in.nextInt();
            int r=0, m=n;
            int i,j;
            for(i = 999;i>=100;i--){
                for(j = 999;j>=m/999;j--){
                    if (i*j < n && i*j > 100000 && isPalindrome(i*j)){
                        r = Math.max(i*j, r);
                        m = r;
                    }
                }
            }

           // System.out.println(i + " * " + j + " = " + i*j);

            System.out.println(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this obviously isn't `java` but it's just a proof of concept on how to use `regex` to batch generate palindromes (of any sort) without having to manually do divisions, modulos, or string reversals :

- To make even length palindromes, simply double the width of the central column starting point.

*(just realized a minor bug of not including the combinations with 2nd and 4th column zeros in the 5-digit variant.)*

---

```
  # gawk profile, created Fri Feb  2 04:52:00 2024

  # BEGIN rule(s)

   BEGIN {
 4      for (_ = _ < _; _++ < 4; ) {
 4          print _, "\f\f\r\t", _______(_)
    }
    }


# Functions, listed alphabetically

 4  function _______(__, _,___,____) {

 4      ___ = "123456789" (____ = "")

 4      if ((__ = int(__)) <= (_^=_<_)+_) {

 2          gsub(/./, _<__ ? ",&&" : __<_ ? ____ : ",&", ___)

 2          return substr(___, _+_)
        }

 2      ____ = __-_-_
 2        __ = (!_)___
 2         _ = "."
 2      gsub(_, "&\\&&", ___)

 3      while (____--)
 3          gsub(_,___, __) < (_ = ("..")_)

 2      gsub(_, ",&", __)
        gsub((_=(_=(".")_)_)_ (_)_ (_)_ "[,]?", "&\n", __)

 2      return substr(__, ++_+_)
    }
```

---

```
 1  1 
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

 2  2 
    11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99

 3  3 
    101,202,303,404,505,606,707,808,909,111,212,313,
 4  414,515,616,717,818,919,121,222,323,424,525,626,
 5  727,828,929,131,232,333,434,535,636,737,838,939,
 6  141,242,343,444,545,646,747,848,949,151,252,353,
 7  454,555,656,757,858,959,161,262,363,464,565,666,
 8  767,868,969,171,272,373,474,575,676,777,878,979,
 9  181,282,383,484,585,686,787,888,989,191,292,393,
10  494,595,696,797,898,999

11  5            
    11011,21012,31013,41014,51015,61016,71017,81018,91019,12021,22022,32023,
12  42024,52025,62026,72027,82028,92029,13031,23032,33033,43034,53035,63036,
13  73037,83038,93039,14041,24042,34043,44044,54045,64046,74047,84048,94049,
14  15051,25052,35053,45054,55055,65056,75057,85058,95059,16061,26062,36063,
15  46064,56065,66066,76067,86068,96069,17071,27072,37073,47074,57075,67076,
16  77077,87078,97079,18081,28082,38083,48084,58085,68086,78087,88088,98089,
17  19091,29092,39093,49094,59095,69096,79097,89098,99099,11111,21112,31113,
18  41114,51115,61116,71117,81118,91119,12121,22122,32123,42124,52125,62126,
19  72127,82128,92129,13131,23132,33133,43134,53135,63136,73137,83138,93139,
20  14141,24142,34143,44144,54145,64146,74147,84148,94149,15151,25152,35153,
21  45154,55155,65156,75157,85158,95159,16161,26162,36163,46164,56165,66166,
22  76167,86168,96169,17171,27172,37173,47174,57175,67176,77177,87178,97179,
23  18181,28182,38183,48184,58185,68186,78187,88188,98189,19191,29192,39193,
24  49194,59195,69196,79197,89198,99199,11211,21212,31213,41214,51215,61216,
25  71217,81218,91219,12221,22222,32223,42224,52225,62226,72227,82228,92229,
26  13231,23232,33233,43234,53235,63236,73237,83238,93239,14241,24242,34243,
27  44244,54245,64246,74247,84248,94249,15251,25252,35253,45254,55255,65256,
28  75257,85258,95259,16261,26262,36263,46264,56265,66266,76267,86268,96269,
29  17271,27272,37273,47274,57275,67276,77277,87278,97279,18281,28282,38283,
30  48284,58285,68286,78287,88288,98289,19291,29292,39293,49294,59295,69296,
31  79297,89298,99299,11311,21312,31313,41314,51315,61316,71317,81318,91319,
32  12321,22322,32323,42324,52325,62326,72327,82328,92329,13331,23332,33333,
33  43334,53335,63336,73337,83338,93339,14341,24342,34343,44344,54345,64346,
34  74347,84348,94349,15351,25352,35353,45354,55355,65356,75357,85358,95359,
35  16361,26362,36363,46364,56365,66366,76367,86368,96369,17371,27372,37373,
36  47374,57375,67376,77377,87378,97379,18381,28382,38383,48384,58385,68386,
37  78387,88388,98389,19391,29392,39393,49394,59395,69396,79397,89398,99399,
38  11411,21412,31413,41414,51415,61416,71417,81418,91419,12421,22422,32423,
39  42424,52425,62426,72427,82428,92429,13431,23432,33433,43434,53435,63436,
40  73437,83438,93439,14441,24442,34443,44444,54445,64446,74447,84448,94449,
41  15451,25452,35453,45454,55455,65456,75457,85458,95459,16461,26462,36463,
42  46464,56465,66466,76467,86468,96469,17471,27472,37473,47474,57475,67476,
43  77477,87478,97479,18481,28482,38483,48484,58485,68486,78487,88488,98489,
44  19491,29492,39493,49494,59495,69496,79497,89498,99499,11511,21512,31513,
45  41514,51515,61516,71517,81518,91519,12521,22522,32523,42524,52525,62526,
46  72527,82528,92529,13531,23532,33533,43534,53535,63536,73537,83538,93539,
47  14541,24542,34543,44544,54545,64546,74547,84548,94549,15551,25552,35553,
48  45554,55555,65556,75557,85558,95559,16561,26562,36563,46564,56565,66566,
49  76567,86568,96569,17571,27572,37573,47574,57575,67576,77577,87578,97579,
50  18581,28582,38583,48584,58585,68586,78587,88588,98589,19591,29592,39593,
51  49594,59595,69596,79597,89598,99599,11611,21612,31613,41614,51615,61616,
52  71617,81618,91619,12621,22622,32623,42624,52625,62626,72627,82628,92629,
53  13631,23632,33633,43634,53635,63636,73637,83638,93639,14641,24642,34643,
54  44644,54645,64646,74647,84648,94649,15651,25652,35653,45654,55655,65656,
55  75657,85658,95659,16661,26662,36663,46664,56665,66666,76667,86668,96669,
56  17671,27672,37673,47674,57675,67676,77677,87678,97679,18681,28682,38683,
57  48684,58685,68686,78687,88688,98689,19691,29692,39693,49694,59695,69696,
58  79697,89698,99699,11711,21712,31713,41714,51715,61716,71717,81718,91719,
59  12721,22722,32723,42724,52725,62726,72727,82728,92729,13731,23732,33733,
60  43734,53735,63736,73737,83738,93739,14741,24742,34743,44744,54745,64746,
61  74747,84748,94749,15751,25752,35753,45754,55755,65756,75757,85758,95759,
62  16761,26762,36763,46764,56765,66766,76767,86768,96769,17771,27772,37773,
63  47774,57775,67776,77777,87778,97779,18781,28782,38783,48784,58785,68786,
64  78787,88788,98789,19791,29792,39793,49794,59795,69796,79797,89798,99799,
65  11811,21812,31813,41814,51815,61816,71817,81818,91819,12821,22822,32823,
66  42824,52825,62826,72827,82828,92829,13831,23832,33833,43834,53835,63836,
67  73837,83838,93839,14841,24842,34843,44844,54845,64846,74847,84848,94849,
68  15851,25852,35853,45854,55855,65856,75857,85858,95859,16861,26862,36863,
69  46864,56865,66866,76867,86868,96869,17871,27872,37873,47874,57875,67876,
70  77877,87878,97879,18881,28882,38883,48884,58885,68886,78887,88888,98889,
71  19891,29892,39893,49894,59895,69896,79897,89898,99899,11911,21912,31913,
72  41914,51915,61916,71917,81918,91919,12921,22922,32923,42924,52925,62926,
73  72927,82928,92929,13931,23932,33933,43934,53935,63936,73937,83938,93939,
74  14941,24942,34943,44944,54945,64946,74947,84948,94949,15951,25952,35953,
75  45954,55955,65956,75957,85958,95959,16961,26962,36963,46964,56965,66966,
76  76967,86968,96969,17971,27972,37973,47974,57975,67976,77977,87978,97979,
77  18981,28982,38983,48984,58985,68986,78987,88988,98989,19991,29992,39993,
78  49994,59995,69996,79997,89998,99999
```